# HTC Desire - ran out of storage - can't interpret solutions offered - need help!

Tags: htc-desire

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I free up more space on my Android (2.2 Froyo) phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3359/how-can-i-free-up-more-space-on-my-android-2-2-froyo-phone)

I have been trying to understand how to solve my phone's problem by reading threads/questions dealing with this problem. However, I cannot interpret the techno-babble. Apparently, I need to 'root' my phone, but I also saw it wasn't for the 'faint-hearted,' of which I am one.

Could someone please direct me to a guide that can explain this process in the easiest terms? Where do I start, how do I proceed, what programs/operating systems do I need, etc. I don't even know what questions to ask at this point.

All I know is that my phone has progressively run out of space, despite my deleting everything I can. It's now running very sluggishly and reboots on its own, and I have to take the battery out often to reset it, etc.

I just don't have the know-how or time to sift through all the threads/websites discussing this. Can someone please help?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Is there a possibility of malware on your phone? See if you can run a scan with [Antivirus Free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.antivirus&hl=en).

Comment: I think the answers to the duplicate should help.  I've never liked HTC phones or the bloatware they load on them....

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange Tlwidmer. Generally speaking it's better to improve existing questions and answers rather than duplicate them, so if you don't understand the answers over at [*How can I free up more space on my Android (2.2 Froyo) phone?*](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3359/how-can-i-free-up-more-space-on-my-android-2-2-froyo-phone) then please feel free ask questions about specific things you have a problem with. When you get to 50 reputation you will be able to add comments to request clarification.