# Im trying to download apps but it says insufficient storage but I have plenty of storage and an sd card

Tags: sd-card, storage, insufficient-memory

I try to download apps like Vine and other apps but, it continuously says insufficient storage and I have an sd card and enough internal storage to download. It makes me angry. Please help, I need don't want but need some apps and it wont let me download.  I have a Samsung galaxy ace style and I got it June 13th. Thanks.

Comment: As you've correctly tagged your question `insufficient-memory`: have you checked with the [corresponding tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info)? That will give you some first-aid, and a.o. tell you the error has nothing to do with your SDCard (you could have Terabytes free there, it wouldn't matter). As this also is a somehow frequent question here, there are more answers already existing, see e.g. [How can I deal with “Low on Space” messages on my Android?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/2305/16575)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on my Huawei Ascend P2, I did a factory reset and it seemed to work, though I highly recommend copying over to your computer every file on your phone before even trying to do so, I don't know the cause myself, the theories I have are:

Virus
Damaged internal memory

If it still doesn't work after the factory reset then you need to take it to a specialist (unless you are one) and take it apart and replace the memory.

P.S Don't treat this as a answer as such, I don't have the reputation to comment (which I think they should allow everyone to do instead of risking losing a ton of rep).

P.S.S Have you checked to see if your SD card is being read by your phone?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution, don't know you have tried or not.
Install any Cache Cleaner apps if possible. Some uncleaned cache may take GBs of data.

If its not possible, delete the files from the cache folders inside the folders in 
Android\data\< some_folder > \