# how do i move the setting to sd card for the downloading apps

Tags: sd-card, insufficient-memory

My problem is, when I download apps in my mobile through playstore which is android it says insufficient space even tho I have space of 16 gb in memory card and the setting is also on ad sd card,it's says primary storage on sd card,but my phone's memory is full,and I have to download it to sd card but still while downloading it says insufficient space

Comment: The apps in android are installed in the /data partition which is in the phone internal storage and have fixed size on some devices like yours ,the android system offers the ability to move some apps to sdcard but not all the apps are compatible and this option is useless ,there is some work around to make your data partition bigger using some space from the SD card but you gonna need root ,busybox and init.d support ,if you have those tell me I will post the full explained methode on how to do it

Comment: Please take a look at our [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info) to get started on this. Especially follow up to [What can I do to manage my phone's internal storage?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/2065/16575) and [How can I deal with “Low on Space” messages on my Android?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/2305/16575)