# How to clear space on your internal storage, other than the trivial measures?

Tags: internal-storage, insufficient-memory, cache, cleanup

After 3.5 years of use, my Android  device (a Xiaomi RedMi 3S) has its internal storage full almost to capacity. I can run its cleaning routine, I can remove photos I snapped and music files I may have stored on it - but over time, more files beyond just that seem to add up. Using the system settings cleaner - same thing: It helps somewhat, but over time, stuff accumulates that it doesn't clean.

I would like, or rather, I need, to remove more data. To do so, I need to be able to differentiate between apps themselves, their reproducible data, their logs/junk leftovers, and the history of interactions, messages and other artifacts due to use. I also need to know what can be deleted and what requires some app-specific deletion facilities.

Obviously I'm not asking for a long list of all of this information for every app; but I would like your advice on how to *gather* such information. Alternatively - other courses of action for clearing up space which I might not have thought about (Maybe - migration of data to my SD card?)

Note: In case it matters, my Settings | Storage screen says:

- Apps & app data: 13.37 GB
- Pictures, Videos: 1.94 GB <- Where are those hiding? :-(
- Audio: 4.72 MB
- Cached data: 539.65 MB <- After running the cleaner
- Other files: 2.86 GB
- System Storage: 6.24 GB

Comment: [How disk space is used on Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216132/218526) and [Where Android apps store data?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218507/218526) and [How to free Internal Storage by moving data or using symlink / bind-mount with Adoptable Storage?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/214706/218526) should answer your question.

Comment: continuing: [What can I do to manage my phone's internal storage?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/2065/16575) // [How can I deal with “Low on Space” messages on my Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/2305/16575) // our [insufficient-memory tag wiki](/tags/insufficient-memory/info)